# mongodb find.count({}) showing less data than find({<with lte & gte clause>})

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am facing a very strange issue in mongoDB.

I have a collection and was trying to find the count of collection:

```
db.getCollection('inventory_items').find({}).count

db.getCollection('inventory_items').count()
```

Above 2 queries returns value: **4847604**

And below query return count: **4847790**

(I found **185** extra records with below query)

```
db.getCollection('inventory_items').find({ "inventoryItemId" :
        { "$lte" : 347429803.0}}).count()
```

Is `find({}).count()` has any restrictions?

why is it not showing me an entire collection count?

Comment: You can export the results of the queries to files, sort them and make a diff to see which are the extra records.

Answer (score 0):

A broken index may cause that difference. Can you try this?

```
db.getCollection('inventory_items').reIndex()
```

Here the docs:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.reIndex/

Comment: Actually it has a large amount of data and issue is on production

Comment: Oh yes, don't do it in production :) Instead, you can export only the `_id` of each record, sort and compare them to see which one is the culprit of that difference.